# QueryExceededMemoryLimitNoDiskUseAllowed with MogoDB Atlas

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I've developed a java application that uses an Atlas MongoDB Serverless DB.
This application performs an Aggregation query with the following steps:

- $match
- $project
- $addFields
- $sort
- $facet
- $project

When I perform a query thats returns a lot of results I'm obtaining this exception: QueryExceededMemoryLimitNoDiskUseAllowed.
I've tried to modify my code adding allowDiskUse: true in the aggregation, but didn't resolve the exception.

I've tried to replicate my aggregation pipeline in Atlas console and found that every think works fine until $facet step that returns

*Reason: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Sort exceeded memory limit of 33554432 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting.*

This is my $facet step:

```
{$facet: {
      paginatedResults: [{ $skip: 0 }, { $limit: 50 }],
      totalCount: [
        {
          $count: 'count'
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm using it to paginate my query results.

Any suggestion to avoid this problem?
I was thinking about making two different query one for the results and one for total count, but I'm not sure this is the best solution.

EDIT: added query

```
db.vendor_search.aggregate(
{$match: {
    $or: [
        {'searchKeys.value': {$regex: "vendor"}},
        {'searchKeys.value': {$regex: "test"}},
        {'searchKeys.valueClean': {$regex: "vendor"}},
        {'searchKeys.valueClean': {$regex: "test"}},
    ],
    buyerId: 7
}},
{$project: {
   companyId: 1,
   buyerId: 1,
   companyName: 1,
   legalForm: 1,
   country: 1,
   supplhiCompanyCode: 1,
   vat: 1,
   erpCode: 1,
   visibility: 1,
   businessStatus: 1,
   city: 1,
   logo: 1,
   location: {$concat : ["$country.value",'$city']},
   searchKeys: {
    "$filter": {
      "input": "$searchKeys",
      "cond": {
        "$or": [
          {$regexMatch: {input: "$$this.value",regex: "vendor"}},
          {$regexMatch: {input: "$$this.value",regex: "test"}}
          {$regexMatch: {input: "$$this.valueClean",regex: "vendor"}},
          {$regexMatch: {input: "$$this.valueClean",regex: "test"}}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}},
{$addFields: {
  searchMatching: {
        $reduce: {
            input: "$searchKeys.type",
            initialValue: [],
            in: {
                $concatArrays: [
                    "$$value", 
                    {$cond: [{$in: ["$$this", "$$value"]},[],["$$this"]]}
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    'sort.supplhiId': { $toLower: "$supplhiCompanyCode" },
    'sort.companyName': { $toLower: "$companyName" },
    'sort.location': { $toLower: {$concat : ["$country.value"," ","$city"]}},
    'sort.vat': { $toLower: "$vat" },
    'sort.companyStatus': { $toLower: "$businessStatus" },
    'sort.erpCode': { $toLower: "$erpCode" }
}},
{$sort: {"sort.companyName": 1}},
{$facet: {
      paginatedResults: [{ $skip: 0 }, { $limit: 50 }],
      totalCount: [
        {
          $count: 'count'
        }
      ]
    }
},
{$project: {paginatedResults:1, 'totalCount': {$first : '$totalCount.count'}}}
)
```

EDIT: Added model

```
{
"buyerId": 1,
"companyId": 869048,
"address": "FP8R+52H",
"businessStatus": "AC",
"city": "Chiffa",
"companyName": "Test Algeria 25 agosto",
"country": {
    "lookupId": 78,
    "code": "DZA",
    "value": "Algeria"
},
"erpCode": null,
"legalForm": "Ltd.",
"logo": "fc4d821a-e814-49e4-96d1-f32421fdaa6d_1.jpg",
"searchKeys": [
    {
        "type": "contact",
        "value": "pebiw81522@xitudy.com",
        "valueClean": "pebiw81522xitudycom"
    },
    {
        "type": "company_registration_number",
        "value": "112211331144",
        "valueClean": "112211331144"
    },
    {
        "type": "vendor_name",
        "value": "test algeria 25 agosto ltd.",
        "valueClean": "test algeria 25 agosto ltd"
    },
    {
        "type": "contact",
        "value": "tredicisf2@ottobre2022.com",
        "valueClean": "tredicisf2ottobre2022com"
    },
    {
        "type": "contact",
        "value": "ty@s.com",
        "valueClean": "tyscom"
    },
    {
        "type": "contact",
        "value": "info@x.com",
        "valueClean": "infoxcom"
    },
    {
        "type": "tin",
        "value": "00112341675",
        "valueClean": "00112341675"
    },
    {
        "type": "contact",
        "value": "hatikog381@rxcay.com",
        "valueClean": "hatikog381rxcaycom"
    },
    {
        "type": "supplhi_id",
        "value": "100059410",
        "valueClean": "100059410"
    },
    {
        "type": "contact",
        "value": "tredici@ottobre2022.com",
        "valueClean": "trediciottobre2022com"
    },
    {
        "type": "country_key",
        "value": "00112341675",
        "valueClean": "00112341675"
    },
    {
        "type": "vat",
        "value": "00112341675",
        "valueClean": "00112341675"
    },
    {
        "type": "address",
        "value": "fp8r+52h",
        "valueClean": "fp8r52h"
    },
    {
        "type": "city",
        "value": "chiffa",
        "valueClean": "chiffa"
    },
    {
        "type": "contact",
        "value": "prova@supplhi.com",
        "valueClean": "provasupplhicom"
    },
    {
        "type": "contact",
        "value": "saraxo2669@dmonies.com",
        "valueClean": "saraxo2669dmoniescom"
    }
],
"supplhiCompanyCode": "100059410",
"vat": "00112341675",
"visibility": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in ATLAS M0 free clusters and M2/M5 shared clusters sort in memory limit is 32 MB. ( [ref](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/free-shared-limitations/#operational-limitations) ) , this limit seems to apply also to [serverless](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/serverless-instance-limitations/#operational-limitations-and-considerations)

For not limited mongod you may usually increase this limit from 32MB for example to 320MB as follow:

```
  db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes: 335544320})
```

You can check the current value with:

```
  db.runCommand( { getParameter : 1, "internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes" : 1 } )
```

But it is best to optimize your queries to not hit this limit , if you post your full query and indexes ( db.collection.getIndexes() perhaps there is a better way ...

Comment: Thanks @R2D2 for the suggestion, I've edited my question and added the query.

I've also tried to do a $facet step that contains my aggregation query and a pipe for the count and thats works fine on atlas but performance are very slow.

Comment: @LucaRiccitelli :  Can you add also some example document so to be easy to test in playground , btw do you have any indexes created , more specifically including the sort.companyName field?

Comment: I've added my model, collection has just one index on couple companyId and buyerId

Comment: Have you tested using compound index including the sort field as follow: db.vendor_search.createIndex({buyerId:1,"sort.companyName":1})

Comment: sort.companyName is a calculated field... How can i create and index on it?

Comment: Ah wait , indeed you are right ...